# How to tell which Javascript file is requesting data in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have two javascript files, call it

- test1.js
- test2.js

they are used to request data from the php file using the following:

```
var xmlhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.open("GET", "../forum/getSomething.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

and I have a php file which is used to do some queries and return the encoded json obj back to one of the js files above, call it

- getSomething.php

my question is, how can I tell which file js is making the request to the php?  Ultimately, I want to state a condition and do something like the this:

```
# inside getSomething.php

# conditional statements
if request from test1.js
    do A
else if request from test2.js
    do B
```

Any tips would be helpful, thanks

Comment: Send some parameters to the php, either GET or POST.

Comment: maybe something in the $_SERVER global you can use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HTTP_REFERER` with `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` but it can be tricky I'll advice you can to identify each `js` request with ID

Example

```
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "../forum/getSomething.php?action=test1", true);
```

Then PHP

```
switch ($_GET['action']) {
    case "test1" :
        // Do Test 1
        break;

    case "test2" :
        // Do Test 2
        break;
}
```

Comment: Using HTTP_REFERRER and REQUESTED_WITH are of no use in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible without having the different files actually specify this themselves - this can for instance be done by adding custom headers to the `XMLHttpRequest`, or by adding additional query params.

Answer (score 0):

You can not generically write code that says "this is coming from script x" - JavaScript engines do not keep track of where any particular line of code come from.

You can always pass explicit data (i.e. in query string) differently from each script i.e.

```
 xmlhttp.open("GET", "../forum/getSomething.php?from=test1", true);
```

Side note: consider using JQuery.ajax for more generic code...